# Angular Dialog Box items get outside the box and not getting cropped

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I'm having a problem in Angular with mat dialog box, when I decrease the screen size, and the box shrinks, some of the elements don't get cropped/hidden by the dialog box but instead just jump out of it...

Also, when I check the element in question with the chrome inspector, I see the element is outlined with dotted lines, I've never had this issue before, whenever I hover over something to inspect it, it just turns blue-ish without dotted lines...

What could be the problem? Why doesn't the dialog box cover this element?

Other things like text do get covered, or moved together with the dialog's borders, like the Apply, Cancel and 'X'(close) buttons... I don't understand...

Here is a picture to demonstrate the issue:

[image: Problem with dialog box]

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You should share code. If possible create stackblitz demo ?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into your layout. if you are using flex try rechecking the width you have assigned to each item in the content of the dialog.